# Iterate in 2 different dictionaries simultaneously in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary, iteration

---EDIT 2---
So I get the question Why I use dictionaries?,
this question is a follow up on this one:  [csv file compression without using existing libraries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647250/csv-file-compression-without-using-existing-libraries-in-python/38662750#38662750)

I Need to compress a 500k csv file (19MB), and I chose to use dictionary to store the ticks in one csv file and symbs in another to be able to Decompress the values

**QUESTION**: How do I iterate the most optimized way? this is just an example of 4 rows, but my real file has 500 000 lines, and takes me for ever to iterate through the list.

I have 3 dictionaries:

```
originalDict = {
               0: ['6NH8', 'F', 'A', '0', '60541567', '60541567', '78.78', '20'], 
               1: ['6NH8', 'F', 'A', '0', '60541569', '60541569', '78.78', '25'], 
               2: ['6AH8', 'F', 'B', '0', '60541765', '60541765', '90.52', '1'], 
               3: ['QMH8', 'F', 'B', '0', '60437395', '60437395', '950.5', '1']
               }
ticks = {0: '6NH8', 1: '6AH8', 2: 'QMH8'}
symbs = {0: 'F,A', 1: 'F,B'}
```

I want to iterate through originalDict and change the "ticks" and then the symbs at `index 1` and `index 2` and then remove `index 2`

so, i.e.

```
0: ['6NH8', 'F', 'A', '0', '60541567', '60541567', '78.78', '20']
```

becomes:

```
[0, '0', '0', '60541567', '60541567', '78.78', '20']
```

I have currently a for loop going through values in originalDict, and inside that another for loop:

```
for values in originalDict.values():
    for ticksKey, ticksValue in ticks.items():
        if values[0] == ticksValue:
            values[0] = ticksKey

    #Change symbs and remove char combination
    for symbsKey, symbsValue in symbs.items():
        comprComb = values[1] + "," + values[2]

        if comprComb == symbsValue:
            values[1] = str(symbsKey)
            #del values[4]
            #del values[4]
            del values[2]
```

ADDITIONAL INFO ADDED:
The reason I have them as dictionary is because the 500 000 lines, some of the ticks occurs more than once, so, I give them a int which is the key in the dict, so goes for the symbs dictionary too.

Comment: if the keys are `0, 1, 2`, why are these not lists?

Comment: what do you mean? as I said, this is just an example of 4 rows that in tis have have 0,1,2... the ticks and symbs dict have different size

Comment: Rewrite `symbs` and `ticks` so that the values become the keys and you don't have to iterate but can just look up the right values?

Comment: Why is this: `ticks = {0: '6NH8', 1: '6AH8', 2: 'QMH8'}` not this: `ticks = ['6NH8','6AH8','QMH8']`

Comment: What is `excSideKey`?

Comment: Use `itervalues()` instead of `values()` and `iteritems()` instead of `items()` to avoid copying data : if your dict is 500k entries this takes forever

Comment: excSideKey  = symbsKey, I changed a little bit to make it more readable, but forgot to change that :)

Comment: mguijarr, what do you suggest?  I need to go through 500k entries, and minimize the csv file i read from, thats why I change the ticks and symbs, that way i give a smaller value at index 0 and remove index 2 to change it for a smaller one

Comment: Why are you using dictionaries for the data? I think you want a list if your keys correspond to list's indices anyway.

Comment: I edited the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all you want to **reverse** the mapping, you are currently looking by value, which is wrong and slow:

```
ticks = {0: '6NH8', 1: '6AH8', 2: 'QMH8'}
symbs = {0: 'F,A', 1: 'F,B'}
```

Using `ticks = {v: k for k, v in ticks.items()}` (same for `symbs`):

```
{'6NH8': 0, 'QMH8': 2, '6AH8': 1} # ticks

{'F,A': 0, 'F,B': 1} # symbs
```

Now that you have good data structures you can do this rather fast.

Now transform the dictionary that holds the data to a list (not sure why it is a dictionary to start with):

```
originalList = [originalDict[k] for k in range(len(originalDict))]
```

And re-map values:

```
for line in originalList:
    line[0] = ticks[line[0]]
    line[1:3] = [symbs["%s,%s" % tuple(line[1:3])]]
```

result:

```
[[0, 0, '0', '60541567', '60541567', '78.78', '20'], [0, 0, '0', '60541569', '60541569', '78.78', '25'], [1, 1, '0', '60541765', '60541765', '90.52', '1'], [2, 1, '0', '60437395', '60437395', '950.5', '1']]
```

Comment: the reason I use the 0: tick1, 1: tick2, is because is i feel it is more "compact" for a file, or am i thinking wrong ?

Comment: How is it any different from a list? And a list is probably more suitable to represent a file as well (`originalDict` -> `originalList`) since it has order. A dictionary does not (at least not naturally. You enforced it using indices as locations, **which is exactly a list**). In dictionaries the keys should always be what you're looking up by. Not what you want to find...

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up the lookup by inverting the keys and values in the `ticks` and `symbs` dicts and then just looking up the right values instead of iterating and comparing all the values in the dicts:

```
ticks_inv = {v: k for k, v in ticks.items()}
symbs_inv = {v: k for k, v in symbs.items()}

for values in originalDict.values():
    if values[0] in ticks_inv:
        values[0] = ticks_inv[values[0]]

    comprComb = "{v[1]},{v[2]}".format(v=values)
    if comprComb in symbs_inv:
        values[1] = symbs_inv[comprComb]
        del values[2]
```

Result is the same as with your code, but should be much faster, particularly if `ticks` and `symbs` are large. Of course, this assumes that the values are unique, but if otherwise your code would not work correctly ether.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is backwards; it's not using the dictionary's key-lookup feature.  Instead of

```
for ticksKey, ticksValue in ticks.items():
    if values[0] == ticksValue:
        values[0] = ticksKey
```

try

```
ticks = {'6NH8': 0, '6AH8': 1, 'QMH8': 2}
...
if values[0] in ticks:
    values[0] = ticks[values[0]]
```

A little weirder looking would be just

```
values[0] = ticks[values[0]] or values[0]
```

If you do that, and similarly with `symbs`, you'll remove all but the necessary outmost loop and see a significant performance improvement.

Comment: thank you, but its through 2 different dictionaries :)