# handling large integers in for loop optimized in python

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, integer, iteration

I'm reading a large csv file (500 000 rows) and adding every row in a dict.
One example row is:

`6AH8,F,B,0,60541765,60541765,90.52,1`

index 4 - `60541765` and index 5 - `60541765`in this case is the same, but it is not always the case. These integers are timestamps that indicates time
in milliseconds-after-midnight format

I want to iterate through every row, and add the large number in a list and address that number to the list index.

i.e:

```
timeList = [60541765, 20531765, ..., 80542765]
```

so the row will be : `6AH8,F,B,0,0,0,90.52,1`

**WHY?** - because the times sometimes occurs more than once in the file.

**Myquestion is:**

Is there a better way to this than store them in a list?

if not:

How do I iterate through the rows, to replace index 4 and 5 the fastest way - right now it takes more than 15 minutes.

Im doing like this at the moment:

```
timeStampList = []
def putTimeStampsInList(inputDict):
  for values in inputDict.values():
      timestamp1 = values[4]

      if values[4] not in timeStampList:
          timeStampList.append(values[4])
```

----------------------- **Additional information** -----------------------

This is an assignment, where I'm supposed to use compression to make a 19MB file smaller without using any 3rd party or framework provided compression libraries for your solution. So I can't use huffman or lz77 and copy it.

I already have a solution to minimize the

```
index 1 - 6AH8

index 2 and 3 - F,B
```

My issue is the time stamps which I can't minimize properly and in a time saving way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely that checking whether a number is in a List in python is an O(n) operation, which will need to be performed for every row in your large dataset, meaning a total of O(n^2) algorithm, which is enormous on 500,000 entries.

My suggestion would be to add a bit of space complexity O(n) to save on time complexity (now making it average case O(n), I think on typical data)

```
timeStampList = []
timeStampSet = set()
def putTimeStampsInList(inputDict):
  for values in inputDict.values():
      timestamp1 = values[4]

      if values[4] not in timeStampSet:
          timeStampList.append(values[4])
          TimeStampSet.add(values[4])
```

Now checking for membership is a constant time operation, so rather than your code cycling through your gigantic list every single time it needs to check if something is in the List, it can just quickly check if it's in the set that you're creating! This should speed up the time of your algorithm significantly.

Once you're done creating the List, you don't need the set anymore, so it won't affect the compression size.

Comment: Thank you James, HOLY Christ that went much faster...but if I want to change the value to the list value: values[4] = timeStampList.index(values[4]), this still iterates and takes time

Comment: You're right - you didn't include that in your sample code, but I suspected you had something like that in your code, which is why I said that average case would be around O(n) - worst case is still O(n^2) because you still have to make that index step. I can think of a solution to make it truly O(n) using a dictionary, but unless you're truly stuck why don't you try to figure it out given the hint that it involves a dictionary, considering this is a homework assignment.

Comment: I was using dictionaries, but i switched it to lists, because the lists took less space (csv file) and people asked me why i didn't do lists instead : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678686/iterate-in-2-different-dictionaries-simultaneously-in-python?noredirect=1#comment64737115_38678686

as I said, the only problem I have is the timestamps

Comment: If you're only using the dictionary temporarily in order to create the list, just like you're only using the set temporarily, does its space matter?

Comment: well, what I do is that I make a list out of the ticker (index 0) - 6AH8, write it to a csv file with an index, before this was in a dictionary, but people said use a list. my index 1 and 2 - F,B, I store them in a another list and write it out to a csv file and remove index 1 and 2 and add the index for the symbol : i.e [6AH8, F,B ... ] and exLis = ['F,A', 'F,B' ..] - I remove index 2 and rename index one as 1 - so : [6AH8, 1 ... ]

Comment: So in that way i compress the 500k lines, but i store them in separate files

Comment: Question, does the set() handle ints and str mixed?

Comment: Yes (This is easily verifiable yourself in the Python shell though)

Comment: for some reason I get same values twice anyway

Comment: It will treat "1" and 1 as distinct, if that's what you're asking. You'll have to use int() or str() to keep them consistent.